# Как отцентрировать span по div'у?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, шрифты

У меня есть кнопка с символом. Сам символ, как бы я его не пытался отцентрировать, не становится в нужное мне положение. Что с этим делать? Я уже и *flex* пытался использовать, и text-align всякие пробовал.
Код кнопки:

```html
<div class="b8" style="background:rgb(255, 0, 255);
        width: 90px;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 413px;
        margin-left: -40px;
        top: 50%;
        border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        -moz-border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        border: 0px solid #000000;
        opacity: 100%;
        filter: blur(0px);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-content: center;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        ">
            <span class="b_span_8" style="
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            opacity: 75%;
            ">8</span>
```

P.S. Здесь все нормально, потому что я не смог добавить стоящий у меня шрифт Pacifico. С ним все ломается. Вот так это выглядит:[image: button]

Comment: скиньте ссылку на шрифт который у Вас установлен

Comment: дело в том что если у символа есть внутренний боковой падинг то центрирование работать не будет но нужен шрифт или скрин проблемы

Comment: @DaniilLoban залил скрин

Comment: Если это шрифт такой, то тогда или подгонять смещение на глазок, или исправлять/менять сам шрифт

Comment: `padding-bottom: 14px;` на мой взляд решает проблему проверьте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько подходит решение но вот можно глянуть с `padding-bottom: 14px;` по факту чуть меньше половины размера шрифта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для того чтобы сделать нормально бэкграунд для шрифта (не выходящий за рамки кнопки) еще пригодится `line-height: 20px;` - тут ровно половина уже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pacifico';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

```html
<body style="background:rgb(0, 0, 0, .5)">
<div class="b8" style="background:rgb(255, 0, 255);
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 413px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    opacity: 100%;
    filter: blur(0px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    ">
        <span class="b_span_8" style="
        font-family: Pacifico;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 75%;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
        background: white; 
        line-height: 20px;
        ">8</span>
   </div>
</div>
```